# How to add a Search option in a ListView in Qml

Tags: qt, qml

I have one Listview and one TextFileld. We are inputting values to TextFiled, that value matched items are displayed in the Listview.

Comment: What is the data source for you ListView, or in other words, what is the 'model' property set to?

Answer (score 1):

If your model is sufficiently small you can also opt for the DelegateModel filter, as found [here](https://martin.rpdev.net/2019/01/15/using-delegatemodel-in-qml-for-sorting-and-filtering.html).

Please note, you need to copy the SortFilterModel.qml file from that site in your project before you can use it. Example usage as follows:

```
SortFilterModel {
    id: delegateModel

    filterAcceptsItem: function(item) {
        return item.modelData % 2 == view.remainder;
    }

    model: <your original model>
    delegate: Text {
        id: item

        text: qsTr("This is item #%1").arg(modelData)
    }
}

ListView {
    model: delegateModel
    //delegate doesn't have to be provided here, it's already in the DelegateModel
}
```

In this example, the input was a integer, leading to a model with number from 0 to that number, which is then filtered on even numbers. In your case you can probably (it's hard to tell without actual code) do something like this:

```
filterAcceptsItem: function(item) {
    return item.model.title.includes(textBoxId.text)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a QAbstractListModel for your ListView, then I recommend a [QSortFilterProxyModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html) to display the search results. For the simple use cases, you tell it what role in the source model to compare against the regex/wildcard string you give it. For more complicated filtering, you can subclass it and override the `filterAcceptsRow` function.

If your model is a QML ListModel, then I recommend the [SortFilterProxyModel](https://github.com/oKcerG/SortFilterProxyModel). It does the same things, but in a declarative way.

Comment: Note that you can use the linked lib with a `QAbstractListModel`. It is just a QSortFilterProxyModel made instantiable and easily usable from QML.  
And `ListModel` is a QAbstractListModel under the hood too.

Comment: @GrecKo thanks for that added info. I've recommended your SortFilterProxyModel a lot. It deserves to be included in the standard Qt libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered `DelegateModel`? It allows you to create "views" on your `ListModel` so you can control what you want to be displayed via the `filterOnGroup` property.

It is rather difficult to comprehend, but, in the following example, I have a `ListModel` containing countries. When you start typing in the search `TextField` it updates a `filterText` property on my `DelegateModel` and it causes the list of the countries to change depending on what you type.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

Page {
    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        TextField {
            id: search
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }
        Frame {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            padding: 0
            ListView {
                anchors.fill: parent
                clip: true
                model: SortFilterDelegateModel {
                    id: sortFilterDelegateModel
                    model: Countries { }
                    filterRole: "country"
                    filterText: search.text
                    //filterRegExp: search.text ? new RegExp(search.text, "i") : null
                    sortRole: "country"
                    sortOrder: ascending.checked ? Qt.AscendingOrder : Qt.DescendingOrder
                    delegate: Frame {
                        width: ListView.view.width - 20
                        property int visibleIndex: DelegateModel.visibleIndex
                        background: Rectangle {
                            color: visibleIndex & 1 ? "#eee" : "#ccc"
                            border.color: "#aaa"
                        }
                        RowLayout {
                            width: parent.width
                            Text {
                                text: visibleIndex + 1
                                color: "grey"
                            }
                            Text {
                                Layout.fillWidth: true
                                text: country
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
                    width: 20
                    policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
                }
            }
        }
        Label { text: qsTr("%1 countries found").arg(sortFilterDelegateModel.count) }
        CheckBox { id: ascending; text: qsTr("Ascending"); checked: true }
    }
}

// SortFilterDelegateModel.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQml.Models

DelegateModel {
    id: delegateModel
    property string filterRole: ""
    property var filterText: null
    property var filterRegExp: null
    property string sortRole: ""
    property var sortRoles: null
    property int sortOrder: Qt.AscendingOrder
    property var sortOrders: null
    property int sortCaseSensitivity: Qt.CaseInsensitive
    property int updateIndex: 0
    onFilterRoleChanged: Qt.callLater(sort, 0)
    onFilterTextChanged: Qt.callLater(sort, 0)
    onFilterRegExpChanged: Qt.callLater(sort, 0)
    onSortRoleChanged: Qt.callLater(sort, 0)
    onSortRolesChanged: Qt.callLater(sort, 0)
    onSortOrderChanged: Qt.callLater(sort, 0)
    onSortOrdersChanged: Qt.callLater(sort, 0)
    onSortCaseSensitivityChanged: Qt.callLater(sort, 0)
    groups: [
        DelegateModelGroup {
            id: allItems
            name: "all"
            includeByDefault: true
            onCountChanged: {
                Qt.callLater(sort, ...(allItems.count === 0 ? [0] : []));
            }
        },
        DelegateModelGroup {
            id: visibleItems
            name: "visible"
        }
    ]
    filterOnGroup: "visible"

    function compareItems(a, b) {
        if (!sortRole && !sortRoles) return 0;
        let _sortRoles = sortRoles ?? [ sortRole ];
        let cmp = 0;
        for (let index = 0; index < _sortRoles.length; index++) {
            let _sortRole = _sortRoles[index];
            let _sortOrder = sortOrders ? sortOrders[index] : sortOrder;
            let valueA = a[_sortRole];
            let valueB = b[_sortRole];
            if (typeof(valueA) === 'number' && typeof(valueB) === 'number') {
                cmp = valueA - valueB;
            } else {
                valueA = valueA.toString();
                valueB = valueB.toString();
                cmp = sortCaseSensitivity === Qt.CaseInsensitive
                      ? valueA.toLowerCase().localeCompare(valueB.toLowerCase())
                      : valueA.localeCompare(valueB);
            }
            if (_sortOrder === Qt.DescendingOrder) cmp = -cmp;
            if (cmp) return cmp;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    function findInsertIndex(item, head, tail) {
        if (head >= count) return head;
        let cmp = compareItems(item, visibleItems.get(head).model);
        if (cmp <= 0) return head;
        cmp = compareItems(item, visibleItems.get(tail).model);
        if (cmp === 0) return tail;
        if (cmp > 0) return tail + 1;
        while (head + 1 < tail) {
            let mid = (head + tail) >> 1;
            cmp = compareItems(item, visibleItems.get(mid).model);
            if (cmp === 0) return mid;
            if (cmp > 0) head = mid; else tail = mid;
        }
        return tail;
    }

    function sort(index) {
        if (index !== undefined) updateIndex = index;
        if (updateIndex === 0) allItems.setGroups(0, allItems.count, [ "all" ] );
        for (let ts = Date.now(); updateIndex < allItems.count && Date.now() < ts + 500; updateIndex++) {
            let visible = true;
            if (filterRole) {
                let item = allItems.get(updateIndex).model;
                let val = item[filterRole];
                if (val && filterText) {
                    visible = visible && (val.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterText.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
                }
                if (val && filterRegExp) {
                    visible = visible && val.match(filterRegExp) !== null;
                }
            }
            if (!visible) continue;
            allItems.setGroups(updateIndex, 1, [ "all", "visible" ]);
            if (!sortRole && !sortRoles) continue;
            let visibleIndex = visibleItems.count - 1;
            if (visibleIndex <= 0) continue;
            let newIndex = findInsertIndex(visibleItems.get(visibleIndex).model, 0, visibleIndex - 1);
            if (newIndex === visibleIndex) continue;
            visibleItems.move(visibleIndex, newIndex, 1);
        }
        if (updateIndex < allItems.count) Qt.callLater(sort)
    }

    Component.onCompleted: Qt.callLater(sort, 0)
}

// Countries.qml
import QtQuick

ListModel {
    property string countries: `Afghanistan
Albania
Algeria
Andorra
Angola
Antigua & Deps
Argentina
Armenia
Australia
Austria
Azerbaijan
Bahamas
Bahrain
Bangladesh
Barbados
Belarus
Belgium
Belize
Benin
Bhutan
Bolivia
Bosnia Herzegovina
Botswana
Brazil
Brunei
Bulgaria
Burkina
Burundi
Cambodia
Cameroon
Canada
Cape Verde
Central African Rep
Chad
Chile
China
Colombia
Comoros
Congo
Congo {Democratic Rep}
Costa Rica
Croatia
Cuba
Cyprus
Czech Republic
Denmark
Djibouti
Dominica
Dominican Republic
East Timor
Ecuador
Egypt
El Salvador
Equatorial Guinea
Eritrea
Estonia
Ethiopia
Fiji
Finland
France
Gabon
Gambia
Georgia
Germany
Ghana
Greece
Grenada
Guatemala
Guinea
Guinea-Bissau
Guyana
Haiti
Honduras
Hungary
Iceland
India
Indonesia
Iran
Iraq
Ireland {Republic}
Israel
Italy
Ivory Coast
Jamaica
Japan
Jordan
Kazakhstan
Kenya
Kiribati
Korea North
Korea South
Kosovo
Kuwait
Kyrgyzstan
Laos
Latvia
Lebanon
Lesotho
Liberia
Libya
Liechtenstein
Lithuania
Luxembourg
Macedonia
Madagascar
Malawi
Malaysia
Maldives
Mali
Malta
Marshall Islands
Mauritania
Mauritius
Mexico
Micronesia
Moldova
Monaco
Mongolia
Montenegro
Morocco
Mozambique
Myanmar, {Burma}
Namibia
Nauru
Nepal
Netherlands
New Zealand
Nicaragua
Niger
Nigeria
Norway
Oman
Pakistan
Palau
Panama
Papua New Guinea
Paraguay
Peru
Philippines
Poland
Portugal
Qatar
Romania
Russian Federation
Rwanda
St Kitts & Nevis
St Lucia
Saint Vincent & the Grenadines
Samoa
San Marino
Sao Tome & Principe
Saudi Arabia
Senegal
Serbia
Seychelles
Sierra Leone
Singapore
Slovakia
Slovenia
Solomon Islands
Somalia
South Africa
South Sudan
Spain
Sri Lanka
Sudan
Suriname
Swaziland
Sweden
Switzerland
Syria
Taiwan
Tajikistan
Tanzania
Thailand
Togo
Tonga
Trinidad & Tobago
Tunisia
Turkey
Turkmenistan
Tuvalu
Uganda
Ukraine
United Arab Emirates
United Kingdom
United States
Uruguay
Uzbekistan
Vanuatu
Vatican City
Venezuela
Vietnam
Yemen
Zambia
Zimbabwe`
    function reload() {
        clear();
        for (let country of countries.split(/\n/)) {
            append({country});
        }
    }
    Component.onCompleted: reload()
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

I have refactored the above into a `FilterDelegateModel` reusable component. Feel free to check it out:

- https://github.com/stephenquan/qt5-qml-toolkit
- https://github.com/stephenquan/qt5-qml-toolkit/wiki/FilterDelegateModel