# Qml combobox turnoff autocomplete

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

I use property **editable** for allowing input text in combobox, and use method **onEditTextChanged** for request input value to DB, response from DB show in **model**. Its work, but autocomplete set in **editText** first value from response, and I cannot choose another value.

How I can turnoff autocomplete?

*qtquick2.12 qt5.12*

Comment: you'll probably have to provide [mcve] so we can understand what you're talking about.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-combobox.html#editable-combobox _ComboBox can be made editable. An editable combo box auto-completes its text based on what is available in the model._

Comment: Although not exactly the same, I demonstrated how to set a filter on a TextField to limit what's shown in a ListView / ListModel with the help of a DelegateModel here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73685281/881441. You could use that as a basis to build something that mimics an editable ComboBox but this approach gives you fine grain control which you can customize to your needs.

Comment: @StephenQuan thanks. I writed popup window like ComboBox with expected behavior.